# Is $ \mathbb{F}_p^{*} $ an integral ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

In my textbook $p$ is a prime numberand $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ is cyclic.

There is $x\in \mathbb{F}_p^*$ such that $x^5=-1$ which means that $(x+1)(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)=0$

The conclusion is that $(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)=0$ but I don't understand why?

Is $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ an integral ring?

From wikipedia I see that $\mathbb{F}_n^*$ is an integral ring implies $n$ is prime but not the opposite.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Reference to Wikipedia?If it claims that, then it has to be fixed. But please note that ${\mathbb F}_n$ (a field and so definitely an integral domain; $n$ must be a power of a prime) is not ${\mathbb Z}_n$ (unless $n$ is prime).

Comment: That conclusion is false. The choice $x=-1$ satisfies the equation $x^5=-1$, but $x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1=5$ which is $\neq0$ (unless per chance you had $p=5$).

Comment: The person who downvoted, thank you to be constructive and say why, othwerwise I can't guess what's wrong with this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are asking 'Is $\mathbb{F}_p^{*}$ an integral ring?' you should first ask yourself 'Is it a ring?'. If you think it is then what is addition, what is multiplication?

**Hint:** Observe the identity of abelian group.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive answer, I see now my error, $0\notin \mathbb{F}_p^*$ so there is no addition and therefore it is only a cyclic group.